# Is the word "isch" only Swiss-German?

Tags: pronunciation, swiss-german, swiss-standard-german

> ig bi Kafka und Kafka isch mi

Swiss people replace the German word *ist* (is) with *isch*, like in the example above, but is this exclusive to their country, or just specific German-speaking cantons? Does this verb count as Swiss standard German, or simply slang/dialect?

Comment: I don't believe they replace it. They pronounce it differently, as do other dialects. In particular, you can expect similarities between [alemannic dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannic_German).

Comment: You writing "slang/dialect" hints you're thinking these would be the same - They aren't.

Comment: Whatever slang that is, I don't understand it. The grammar doesn't make sense in any of the dialects I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speaking "ist" as "isch" is neither slang nor specific to Swiss German - It is the common way how [Alemannic](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Dialekte) (rather: "westoberdeutsch") dialects that roughly range from French Alsace in the west to Austrian Vorarlbergerisch in the east, and Swabian in the north to Swiss German dialects in the south  morph the "-st" suffix to "-sch".

All of these dialects share some common traits, the most known are the phenmenon you encountered, or building the diminuitive with "-le" or "-li" instead of "-chen".